# Dismiss UIAlertView once all items appear in View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, events, uialertview

I would like to show a UIAlertView while my items are being fetched (from the EKEventStore) by my table view controller. Once all my items have appeared I would like the alert to disappear.

I tried dismissing the alert in viewDidAppear() but that doesn't work. My alert just stays around. And I can't just dismiss it after the code to fetch my items them because the fetching runs on its own thread and continues executing stuff after it - hence, my alert will just appear and immediately disappear.

```
let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Loading", message: "Please wait...", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 10, 37, 37)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
        loadingIndicator.center = self.view.center;
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

        self.alert.setValue(loadingIndicator, forKey: "accessoryView")
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        self.alert.show()
    }

    // Code to fetch my items here...
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)       
    self.alert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(-1, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `-1` index works?  Have you debugged to find if the load and dismiss functions are getting called in the order that you would expect?

Comment: The index works. This code works in other scenarios (i.e., with an NSTimer calling the dismiss after five seconds.) I just need to find the event that I could use for when all my items appear in the table view controller.

Comment: How about the same location where you tell the `loadingIndicator` to stop animating?

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code with how you tried to dismiss the alert after the data finished loading. So far you've posted all of the wrong code.

Comment: What do you mean? It's right there inside viewDidAppear().

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is not where you should do this. You need to do it when the data is done loading. You need to update your question that loads the data so we can point out the proper place and way to dismiss the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be in `viewDidAppear()`. `viewDidAppear` loads everytime your view appears (which is why it is dismissing this right away).

You need to instead dismiss this somewhere in your code after everything you want to happen is done loading.  Possibly here: (but that depends on what exactly the fetch of your items looks like)

```
// Code to fetch my items here...
self.alert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(-1, animated: true)
}
```